# Simple programmatic generation and compilation of grammar in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr

I want to programmatically take a grammar in the form a String and generate the Java for it as a String or Strings. I want to do this all in memory, no files involved. I took a look at org.antlr.Tool source but I was hoping there would be some simpler way to do what I want rather than rewrite Tool without files. Does something already exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does something already exist?

No, not AFAIK. Not in ANTLR's public API, nor some existing 3<sup>rd</sup> party tool that can do this.